# Create "function" to run bash?

Tags: bash

I have the following bash:

```
cd /aPath/
for x in y.*.gz
> do something $file.dd.mm.yyyy >> /anotherPath/aFile
> done
```

I would like to pass in an argument to this file which will represent the month to insert in to 'mm'. So I would like to be able to call from the command line:

myFunc 08

and it would run:

```
cd /aPath/
for x in y.*.gz
> do something $file.dd.08.yyyy >> /anotherPath/aFile
> done
```

How do I do this/can I define something in my bash_profile ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add the function into my `/home/user/.bashrc`

in example

```
myFunc() {
  mm=$1
  FILES=/home/user/*
  for f in $FILES; do
    if [[ $f == filename.dd.$mm.yyyy ]]; then
      ls -la $f
    fi
  done
}
```

and remembering to reload **.bashrc** file with the command `source ~/.bashrc`, I would call the function from the shell.

`mm=$1` will get the first parameter(argument) you passed to the function by calling `myFunc 08` and put it into `$mm` variable (which is pretty useless step, you can directly use `$1` variable wherever you need into the function)